# ABC size too high, even when there are no branches, assignments, or conditionals

Tags: ruby, graphics, rubocop

I am confused here about what RuboCop is complaining about.

> "Assignment Branch Condition size for draw is too high. [29/15]"

for the method below:

```
class Ball
  attr_reader :color
  attr_reader :center
  attr_reader :radius
  attr_reader :dir
  attr_reader :x, :y
  attr_reader :w, :h
  attr_accessor :worldWidth
  attr_accessor :worldHeight
  ...
  # Draw the ball into this device context
  def draw(dc)
    dc.setForeground(color)
    dc.fillArc(x, y, w, h, 0, 64 * 90)
    dc.fillArc(x, y, w, h, 64 * 90, 64 * 180)
    dc.fillArc(x, y, w, h, 64 * 180, 64 * 270)
    dc.fillArc(x, y, w, h, 64 * 270, 64 * 360)
  end
  ...
```

Because there are *no* assignments, branches, nor conditionals here!

What am I missing? And what is so bad about this function anyway? It would seem silly to have to change it, and I am not clear on what "benefit" it would bring. Please clarify!

Comment: I don't fully understand how ABC (assignment/branch/condition) works but you can see from the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABC_score) page that functions calls are generally treated as branches. [here](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/blob/master/lib/rubocop/cop/metrics/abc_size.rb) is the rubocop source for determining this score, and [here](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/blob/master/config/default.yml) are the rubocop defaults (the default max ABC score is 15).

Answer (score 4):

The formula RuboCop uses to calculate the ABC size is:

```
sqrt(assignments^2 + branches^2 + condition^2)
```

A message send (a.k.a. method call) is considered one "branch" in RuboCop. Since, as you pointed out, there are no assignments or conditions in this case, the ABC size for this method is given by `sqrt(branches^2)` or, simply, `branches`.

We can check that this is correct by counting the message sends in the method:

- 1 x `#setForeground`
- 1 x `#color`
- 4 x `#fillArc`
- 4 x `#x`
- 4 x `#y`
- 4 x `#w`
- 4 x `#h`
- 7 x `#*`

for a grand total of `29`, which is the ABC size we expected.

---

> And what is so bad about this function anyway? It would seem silly to have to change it, and I am not clear on what "benefit" it would bring.

Don't make the mistake of thinking RuboCop is omnipotent. It neither reads nor understands code. It doesn't have a notion of "better" code. It applies some (rather primitive) heuristics that gives us a proxy measure of "quality." It is up to us to interpret that and decide what action to take.

A common case where RuboCop struggles is declarative DSLs. In those cases, it's usually best to disable the cops that break down. RuboCop offers different levels of granularity to do this. You can do it inline, using `rubocop:disable CopName` (remember to enable it again), on a file or directory basis in `.rubocop.yml`, or for the entire project in the same file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm working on a project where Rubocop has been made part of the build process. That is to say, it will fail the build if Rubocop isn't happy. I may be disabling Rubocop quite a bit just to get work done!

Thanks again.

Comment: @flajann: You're welcome! You can find more information on the different configuration options here: http://rubocop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/

Comment: You make me understand this as I couldn't ever before. Thank you so much!